# Where can I find out where a package has been installed to?

Tags: linux, yum, fedora-14

Fedora 14 xfce

I have installed a package using `yum install package-name`.

However, I can't seen to find out where it has been installed to.

Is there any command that will tell me what directory the files have been installed to?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can just use the `rpm` tool for this.

```
rpm -ql package-name
```

Will list all files installed by that package (that's que-ell).

Answer (score 10):

You could open a terminal session and use **whereis**:

```
[linker3000@aa1 ~]$ whereis vi
vi: /bin/vi /usr/share/man/man1/vi.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1p/vi.1p.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

The above will work but I found rpm did not work for development libraries (e.g. libssl-dev). It may have been me, but maybe not. Here is another approach:

If you have Synaptic Package Manager you can:

1. Locate the package under **Installed**.
2. Right click and select **Properties**.
3. Click the **Installed Files** tab.

This will show you where all the files are installed. An especially useful piece of information for development libraries that are installed in multiple locations.

Answer (score 0):

In newer Fedora versions, `dnf` is used. Use:

`dnf list installed`

or, to filter the packages where the name starting with "jackson", use

`dnf list installed "jackson*"`

Comment: This doesn't show where the package is installed, just which version and from which dnf repository